# Can I still submit iOS 5.1 apps to the app store (Oct 2012 )?

Tags: app-store, xcode4.3, xcode4.5, iphone-4, iphone-5

I started building an iOS app with xCode 4.3.2 , using armv6 and armv7 instruction sets. My deployment target is iOS5.1 . Now that iPhone 5 is released, and xCode 4.5 drops support for armv6, and replaces it with armv7s , what is the correct approach to submitting apps to the app store?

**I'm afraid that if I submit the app incorrectly, the app store review team would try to launch the app on iPhone 5, running armv7s , and the app would not run.**

Should I update to xCode 4.5, and build my apps against iOS6 now, even though I do not have an iPhone 5 to test it on?

Thank you for any clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I update to xCode 4.5, and build my apps against iOS6 now, even though I do not have an iPhone 5 to test it on?

You can submit an app that does not exploit the iPhone specific features (namely, the taller screen). If your app works on iPhone 4, then it will work on iPhone 5, although in a special mode where the visual content of your app is centered on screen, with black bands both above and below it.

On the other hand, you can use the Xcode 4.5 simulator to ensure that your app works on iPhone 5, if you are worried about it. Then you could change your code base to make it run on iPhone 5 and still provide an official build for the App Store made with Xcode 4.3. This is good for all except performance tuning and fixing memory management issues; but you can work on those points on your current iPhone/iPad, whatever.

With Xcode 4.5, Apple decided to make a move towards discontinuing support for older devices: the original iPhone, iPhone 3G, and the first two versions of iPod Touch. So, if you want to support iPhone 5, you will be forced to discontinue support for those devices. I don't think it is a big issue, although I myself have got an old iPod Touch 2nd Gen and I cannot foresee a bright future for it.

If in doubts about supporting iOS5 vs. iOS6, you could also have a look at [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259926/updating-apps-to-ios6/12260063#12260063).

Hope this helps.